# How to escape backslashes in `sed` inside `find ... -exec`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, filenames

I want to change a line in some files in different subdirectories. The files will always have the extension `.dct` and they will always be in a subdirectory called `mod` within another subdirectory of the working directory (but there are many `mod` subdirectories, so I use `find`). But the strings that I want to change are directories (Windows -> Unix).

I can get the relevant files with `find . -type f -path '*/mod/*.dct`. I've tried changing the relevant lines with `sed -e 's/cd c:\\project\\data\\/cd \/project\/data\//' $(basename {}) > $(basename {}).mod`.

I narrowed it down to the escaped backslashes being the culprit. This works:

```
find . -type -f -path '*/mod/*.dct' -execdir sh -c "sed -e 's/c://' $(basename {}) > $(basename {}).mod"
```

This does not:

```
find . -type -f -path '*/mod/*.dct' -execdir sh -c "sed -e 's/c:\\//' $(basename {}) > $(basename {}).mod"
```

This is the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

The `char 7` part made me think that there is some problem with the escaping. It looks like that is the case but I don't know how to solve it. For illustration, this works:

```
find . -type -f -path '*/mod/*.dct' -execdir sh -c "sed -e 's/c:\\//' $(basename {}) > $(basename {}).mod"
```

So it looks like `sed -e 's/c:\\///'` is escaped to "replace `c:\/` with nothing"  and `sed -e 's/c:\\//'` is escaped to "replace `c:\/` with ..." (and that throws an error) instead of "replace `c:\` with nothing."

NB: using `-execdir` and `basename` instead of `-exec` might be overkill, but I read somewhere that it was a good form.

Comment: The quoting used is the double quotes, so you have to play by their rules.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you mean that I should enclose the `sed` instructions in double quotes? [Edit] Tried and same error.

Comment: You need to escape as though you were in double quotes.

Comment: It would help if you gave enough information so that someone could run your command and reproduce your error without having to produce their own sample data. You could probably simplify and generalize the problem statement a bit too.

Comment: It also looks to me like you have a few typos in your commands, e.g. `-type -f` should read `-type f` and there should be a terminating semicolon for the `-execdir` option.

Comment: @igal re typos and semicolon: you're right, fixed it. Re: more information - not sure what additional information exactly would be necessary and as for a minimal working example, since the directory structure is part of the problem (because it creates the need to use `find` and then nest quotes), I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: your comment went to the heart of the problem, but I had trouble finding good documentation. Would you mind giving some pointers to relevant documentation or search words?

Comment: @Ole I've updated my solution to include a restatement of the problem which should illustrate what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of your question is how to replace a backslash (i.e. `\`) with a forward slash (i.e. `/`) by calling `sed` from `find`. To do that you have to double-escape the backslashes, because the string is going to be processed twice: once by the invocation of `find` and then a second time by the invocation of `sed`. This should give you the following:

```bsh
find . -type f -path '*/mod/*.dct' -execdir sh -c "sed -e 's/cd c:\\\\project\\\\data\\\\/cd \/project\/data\//' $(basename {}) > $(basename {}).mod" \;
```

A more detailed explanation follows.

---

First let's set up a slightly simpler example of your problem:

```bsh
# Create a target directory
mkdir -p /tmp/dir1/mod/dir2

# Create a text file containing a backslash
echo '\' > /tmp/dir1/mod/dir2/file.dct
```

Now let's try to use `find` and `sed` to replace that backslash with a forward slash:

```bsh
find /tmp/dir1 -type f -path '*/mod/*.dct' -execdir sh -c "sed -e 's/\\/\//' $(basename {})" \;
```

This produces the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

That's because the `sed` command which is being executed is this:

```bsh
sed -e 's/\/\//' ./file.dct
```

You verify that you get the same error by running this command directly, e.g.:

```bsh
sed -e 's/\/\//' /tmp/dir1/mod/dir2/file.dct
```

You can also check this by running `echo` from within the `find` command, e.g.:

```bsh
find /tmp/dir1 -type f -path '*/mod/*.dct' -execdir echo "sed -e 's/\\/\//' $(basename {})" \;
```

To fix the command we double-escape the backslashes:

```bsh
find . -type f -path '*/mod/*.dct' -execdir sh -c "sed -e 's/\\\\/\//' $(basename {})" \;
```

This produces the desired result:

```
/
```

Comment: @Ole I updated my solution but I wasn't fast enough; you commented before I was finished. The explanation is now much more detailed.

Comment: @Ole Yeah, I wasn't sure how many slashes you were trying to replace. It would have been good to include those as strings outside of any commands, e.g. you wanted "c:\project\data" to go to "/project/data". I don't use Windows very often and I couldn't remember how many backslashes follow the drive letter.

Comment: I deleted the comment. Couldn't figure out a way to edit to acknowledge your more detailed response. The more detailed response is great.

Comment: also, thank you for showing me how to give a proper minimal working example. I will do that in the future.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy coding.